# tikz arc with -latex arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Why the arc does not fit over the circle if we use `-latex` arrow tip? Maybe some bug or some bad math computations?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw         (0:1cm) arc (0: 180:1cm) arc (180:0:1cm and 2cm);
\draw         (0:1cm) arc (0:-180:1cm);
\draw[->]     (0:1cm) arc (0:  80:1cm);
\draw[-latex] (0:1cm) arc (0:- 80:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You will find a description of why this is happening in the manual 16.3.8 (it is not an error). To avoid it use `\usetikzlibrary{bending}`.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen, perfect! It solved my problem. If you wish, please, post an answer.

Comment: `-latex` isn't provided by `arrows.meta`, is it? Doesn't that provide `-Latex`?

Comment: @cfr, sorry. To be true, that library I am using in other code part.

Comment: I think `decorations.markings` is better than `bending` in this case

Comment: @hpekristiansen Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution using marking. It does not draw any additional curve. Thus there is no chance to have any curve overlap.

```
\documentclass[11pt,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    arrow at end/.style={
        decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .999 with{
                \arrow{#1};
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw                    (0:1cm) arc (0: 180:1cm) arc (180:0:1cm and 2cm);
\draw                    (0:1cm) arc (0:-180:1cm);
\draw[arrow at end=>]    (0:1cm) arc (0:  80:1cm);
\draw[arrow at end=latex](0:1cm) arc (0:- 80:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]